How can I add quote blocks to Sanity? (NextJS)
I am working on a NextJS project. The blog page of this project is using Sanity for content management. I want to be able to create block quotes like this: 
I looked through their documentation and also the Sanity studio but didn't find what I need, any help is appreciated.

Adding a block to your Rich Text Editor requires 2 (sometimes 3) things:

A schema.
A view component that you can add to the <PortableText />
(optionally) A custom input

There are two ways you could go about this:

The easy way: where all block quotes look the same
The advanced way: where you can add a new custom input with additional fields such as "colour" or "icon"

I'll go over the easy way, but if you're interested in the advanced/custom method, you can check out the official guide.
Using the predefined blockquote type
If you can locate the schema where there is an array of block types, like this:
export default defineType({
  title: 'Block Content',
  name: 'blockContent',
  type: 'array',
  of: [
    defineArrayMember({
      title: 'Block',
      type: 'block',
      styles: [
        { title: 'Normal', value: 'normal' },
        { title: 'H1', value: 'h1' },
        { title: 'H2', value: 'h2' },
      ],
      lists: [],
      marks: {
        decorators: [],
        annotations: []
      },
    }),
    // Custom block types go here
  ],
})

You'll simply append the following to your styles array:
      styles: [
        { title: 'Normal', value: 'normal' },
        { title: 'H1', value: 'h1' },
        { title: 'H2', value: 'h2' },
        { title: 'Quote', value: 'blockquote' }, // <-- the new type
      ],

Then, head over to where your <PortableText /> is being used. You'll need to either add a new components prop or modify the existing one.
In this example, it might look something like this:
import { PortableText, type PortableTextBlock, type PortableTextComponents } from 'next-sanity'

export default function CustomPortableText({
  value,
}: {
  value: PortableTextBlock[]
}) {
  const components: PortableTextComponents = {
    block: {
      normal: ({ children }) => {
        return <p>{children}</p>
      },
      blockquote: ({ children }) => {
        /** 
         * Define how you would like your blockquote to appear here 
         * (could be a custom component you import from somewhere else)
         */
        return <blockquote>{children}</blockquote>
      }
    },
    list: {},
    marks: {},
    types: {}
  }

  return <PortableText components={components} value={value} />
}


For more info about portable text and customizing Sanity's editor, you can check out their docs.
Hope this gets you headed in the right direction!

Do you want to create a schema that includes images and rich text with the array?
  defineField({
          name: 'carousel',
          title: 'Carousel',
          type: 'array',
          of: [{type: 'carousel'}],
        }),

and then
export default {
  name: 'carousel',
  title: 'Carousel*',
  type: 'document',
  validation: (Rule) => Rule.required(),
  fields: [
    defineField({
      name: 'icon',
      title: 'icon',
      type: 'image',
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'text',
      title: 'text',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{type: 'block'}],
    }),
  }

something like this will work if I understand what you want.
You don't need to create this differently you can directly create a single schema also.
